# Symmetric Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider V a vector space and the symmetric algebra $S(V^*)$
is it possible to define the polynomial on $V$, $R[V]$ canonically ?
I.e. without a use of base ?
And show this is isomorphic to the symmetric algebra ?

Comment: Well, what prevents you from defining polynomial functions on $V$ as $S(V^*)$? It clearly makes sense: $V^*$ consists of all linear functions, and multiplying them to to create polynomials is a natural thing. Or are you worried about the possible side effects in positive characteristic?

Comment: Polynomials on $V$ are precisely elements of $S(V^{\ast})$ by the universal property of the symmetric algebra. There are no characteristic issues here. 

Answer (score 1):

This has come up several times before:

[Definition of the symmetric algebra in arbitrary characteristic for graded vector spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7080/)

[Is there a notation for the symmetric / antisymmetric subspaces of a tensor power that distinguishes them from the symmetric / exterior power?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54698/)

[Symmetric powers and duals of vector bundles in char p](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34452/)

[Is $Sym^n (V^*) \cong Sym^n (V)^\ast$ naturally in positive characteristic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15336/)